# Where do I place my return true statement

Tags: javascript, function, boolean

This is a basic javascript question I just want to better understand. I'm trying to understand if it matters where I place my return true statement. Here's the example code:

```
function isValid(input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length - 2; i++) {
        var charOne = input.charAt(i);
        var charTwo = input.charAt(i + 1);
        var charThree = input.charAt(i + 2);

        if (charOne === charTwo && charOne === charThree) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

isValid("ABB");
```

This returns true, but also returns true if I place the return true statement here:

```
function isValid(input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length - 2; i++) {
        var charOne = input.charAt(i);
        var charTwo = input.charAt(i + 1);
        var charThree = input.charAt(i + 2);

        if (charOne === charTwo && charOne === charThree) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // Moved this return statement
}

isValid("ABB");
```

Is one way wrong and the other correct?

Comment: Of course it matters; the two locations for the `return` statement result in entirely different programs. In the first, the `for` loop is guaranteed to exit during the first iteration. The second will process each value for `i` until the condition is met or the loop condition fails. Try running each version of the function with the input `"ABCCC"`

Answer (score 1):

Your first version, you are returning `true` within the for loop. That means its only going to execute your loop once and then return.  That's likely a bug.

Your second version is likely correct.  The return `true` statement executes from the function after the for-loop completes all iterations from `[i..length-2)`.

Answer (score 1):

second one, since in the first one after each iteration , you check if characters are equal and it will `return false`  or  `return true` in the first iteration itself.In, second one you check for all combinations and if it's never false then it must be true.

Answer (score 0):

When you `return` inside a for loop you finish the whole loop and carry on outside it.

So the answer is it depends, if you want to miss out an item and carry on looping after the return statement then doing a return isn't what you want.

The return you put outside of the loop allows the loop to complete before returning the result.

*Note* a useful keyword you can use inside a loop if you want to finish the iteration rather than breaking the whole loop is `continue`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one is wrong necessarily. I actually prefer a slightly different approach.
For clarity I generally will do something like this. So it is clearly one or the other. 
With a return it is obvious that calculations within the function stop at that point. I just like it to look obvious.

```
        if(charOne === charTwo && charOne === charThree) {
          return false;
        } {
          return true;
        }
```